# Hashmap's values update every time if I put new values & keys in it

Tags: java, list, for-loop, hashmap

So the problem is that if I add a new key&value pair to my hashmap it gets updated ,

right now the key is a number like and ID and the value is a list what countains numbers and 
every id should have different list but it's broken for some reason.
So I would like to achieve different list values.
There is the code:

```
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> map22 = new HashMap<>();
int countrrr = 0;
List<Integer> asd = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <50; i++) {
    asd.add(i);
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        countrrr++;
        map22.put(countrrr,asd);
        System.out.println(asd);
        asd.clear();
    }
}
System.out.println(map22);
```

Comment: The problem is that you are mutating the exact same list object each time. If you move `List<Integer> asd = new ArrayList<>();` inside the for-loop, it should work as you expect.

Comment: but if I create a new list every time the for loops, it will only containn 1 elemnt right ? or no ?

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `asd.clear()` when you do that.

Comment: No,I mean I want the list to contain the number like 1,2,3,4,5 then if it's dividable by 5, it should be stored in the map, ,but the code what you said below is just storing number like 5 and then 10 then 15

Comment: So right now it gives me {1=[46, 47, 48, 49], 2=[46, 47, 48, 49] etc.... but it should give back 1=[1,2,3,4,5] ,2=[6,7,8,9,10] That's why I need to clear it every time @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is that your code currently uses only one List for storing all results (because `HashMap.put()` doesn't make clones of its arguments.) You need to create a fresh list after storing a result in the HashMap.

Something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> map22 = new HashMap<>();
int countrrr = 0;
List<Integer> asd = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <50; i++) {
    asd.add(i);
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        countrrr++;
        map22.put(countrrr, asd);
        System.out.println(asd);
        asd = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
System.out.println(map22);
```

Comment: Could you please explain me what does "HashMap.put() doesn't make clones of its arguments." really mean ? I don't really understand that.Or It means that I can only store a certain object in the hasmap only 1x ? and that's why I have to make a new object every time ?

Comment: @elisaa it means that after `map22.put(countrrr,asd);` you don't magically have two lists (one referenced by `asd` and one in the HashMap) - you created only one list and you therefore have only one list even if you can now access it via `asd` and via the HashMap. If you then write `asd.clear();` the contents of the list are cleared and because the HashMap contains a reference to this same list a `map22.get(countrrr)` will also show that the list is empty.

Comment: You can store as many references to a single list in a HashMap as you want. But if the list contains something that you want to keep you have to either make a copy of that list or create a new list to work with.